# Split list into two

Tags: list, f#, f#-scripting

I would like to implement a function that takes as input a size n and a list. This function will cut the list into two lists, one of size n and the rest in another list. I am new to this language and have a hard time learning the syntax.

The main problem I have is that is finding a way to express a size of the list without using any loops or mutable variables.

Can anyone give a me some pointers?

Comment: What have you tried? At least you should give us a non-working version to show your efforts?

Comment: Hint: you do not need to express the length of the list - all you need is a way to decrement `n`, and to check if it has reached zero.

Comment: This may be slightly off topic, but there was a rather neat solution (by Juliet) that split a list in two halves, without knowing/specifying the length in advance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866640/split-list-into-two-equal-lists-in-f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
let split n list =
  let rec not_a_loop xs = function
    | (0, ys) | (_, ([] as ys)) -> (List.rev xs), ys
    | (n, x::ys) -> not_a_loop (x::xs) (n-1, ys)
  not_a_loop [] (n, list)
```

Comment: I dont understand too much your code but it seems that it uses a loop. I was thinking of doing some recurisve calls where i would specify n as the index and  having as a base case return when the item in position n is found .. What do you think?

Comment: That's more or less what this does, accumulating elements prior to `n` along the way.

Comment: @user1072706 : No, it uses a recursive function _named_ loop. The name is arbitrary, don't let it confuse you.

Comment: Thanks, what does the statement | (_,([] as ys)) translate to?

Comment: `|` is "or" in a pattern match, so it says: if `n` is zero or the input list is empty. `ys` is being bound to the input list regardless of which side of the "or" is true.

Comment: There's a certain amount of irony here, considering the inner function is tail-recursive and therefore most likely _will_ compile to a loop.

Comment: @user1072706: See my answer for an illustration. You may have a better understanding of what's going on inside recursion.

Comment: @user1072706 For what it's worth, you can find this and more extensions in [FSharpx](http://nuget.org/packages/FSharpx.Core) ([line reference](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/Collections.fs#L199))

Comment: such a shame ya didn't take ya  time to explain how that function works.

Answer (score 11):

Let's start with the function's type signature. Since it gets `n` and a list as arguments and returns a pair of lists, you have a function `split`:

```
val split : int -> 'a list -> 'a list * 'a list
```

Here is one approach to implement this function:

```
let split n xs =
  let rec splitUtil n xs acc =
    match xs with
    | [] -> List.rev acc, []
    | _ when n = 0 -> List.rev acc, xs
    | x::xs' -> splitUtil (n-1) xs' (x::acc)
  splitUtil n xs []
```

The idea is using an accumulator `acc` to hold elements you have traversed and decreasing `n` a long the way. Because elements are prepended to `acc`, in the end you have to reverse it to get the correct order.

The function has two base cases to terminate:

- There's no element left to traverse (`xs = []` at that point).
- You have gone through the first `n` elements of the list (`n` decreases to `0` at that time).

Here is a short illustration of how `split` computes the result:

```
   split 2 [1; 2; 3] // call the auxiliary function splitUtil
~> splitUtil 2 [1; 2; 3] [] // match the 3rd case of x::xs'
~> splitUtil 1 [2; 3] [1] // match the 3rd case of x::xs'
~> splitUtil 0 [3] [2; 1] // match the 2nd case of n = 0 (base case)
~> List.rev [2; 1], [3] // call List.rev on acc
~> [1; 2], [3]
```

Comment: what role does the last "splitUtil n xs []" play in the function?

Comment: @user1072706: it is an *auxiliary* function to avoid declaring `split` with an extra argument which is always an empty list. You can use `splitUtil` directly, then everything starts from the 2nd line.

Comment: @user1072706, it calls the inner function (`splitUtil`) with the initial parameters of the outer function (`split`), plus an empty `acc` to fill.

Answer (score 2):

New solution - splitAt is now built into List and Array.  See commit around 2014 on github.  I noticed this today while using F# in VS.2015

Now you can simply do this...

```
let splitList n list = 
    List.splitAt n list
```

And as you might expect the signature is...

```
n: int -> list: 'a list -> 'a list * 'a list
```

Example usage:

```
let (firstThree, remainder)  = [1;2;3;4;5] |> (splitList 3)
printfn "firstThree %A" firstThree
printfn "remainder %A" remainder
```

Output:

```
firstThree [1; 2; 3]
remainder [4; 5]
```

Github for those interested:  https://github.com/dsyme/visualfsharp/commit/1fc647986f79d20f58978b3980e2da5a1e9b8a7d

Answer (score 0):

One more way, using `fold`:

```
let biApply f (a, b) = (f a, f b)

let splitAt n list = 
  let splitter ((xs, ys), n') c =
    if n' < n then
      ((c :: xs, ys), n' + 1)
    else
      ((xs, c :: ys), n' + 1)
  List.fold splitter (([], []), 0) list 
  |> fst 
  |> biApply List.rev
```

[Here](http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/05/catamorphisms-part-one/) is a great series on folds than you can follow to learn more on the topic.

Comment: Doesn't this function walk through the *whole* list, instead of just up to n?