# Easiest way to remove the last element from list

Tags: f#

I am writing a function that will take a list of integers, for example :

```
let x = [1..5]
```

and should return a shuffled list like below :

```
[1;5;2;4;3]
```

So, it should take first element and then last, then 2nd element and before last and so on...

I have written this function so far:

```
let rec reshuffle list: List<int> =
  match list with
  | [] -> []
  | head :: tail -> [head;list |> List.last] @reshuffle tail
```

I am getting this answer :

```
[1; 5; 2; 5; 3; 5; 4; 5; 5; 5]
```

It seems that is because each time the function is being recursively done, the last element is not being removed. How do I remove both head and tail in the function?

Comment: You could use the slicing syntax - `items.[.. items.Length-1]`.

Comment: i changed to this line :     `| head :: tail -> [head;list |> List.last] @shuffle tail.[.. tail.Length-1]`

But now when i test the function i get an index out of range error

Comment: From here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1984510/6896871
It also seems that list does not support slicing

Comment: Not certain `list` type is the best suited for that, I'll probably convert it to an `array` inside the function and then back to `list` when returned

Comment: @JuliusKnafl That isn't true anymore; F# 4.0 supports slicing for lists as well.

Comment: @Sehnsucht Actually, one of the requirement is to use lists to do this. And it should follow the following structure : int list -> int list

Comment: @JuliusKnafl yeah just saw that, but am still getting the out of range error

Comment: @JuliusKnafl That is because you don't account for the empty list case; if the length is zero, you'd slice to a negative index, which will of course fail.

Comment: @JuliusKnafl you could work with 2 lists then the given one and the same reversed. Then you almost have to zip (creating sublist instead of pairs) them together and take half (with handling for odd/even length case) and flatten those sublists

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev is the 2nd line not matching an empty list?

Comment: It is, but for catching this case, it's in the wrong place - tail is `[]` when the input of the current recursion is a single element list, so you're not coming through the `[]` case in the match expression; you're just trying to slice an empty tail later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you guys for all your responses. I finally came to this solution:

```
let rec reshuffle list: List<int> =
  match list with
  | [] -> []
  | head :: tail -> head :: reshuffle (List.rev tail)
```

Answer (score 4):

If we assume no library function is allowed and trying to avoid processing the list again and again for "nothing", I propose this.

We first reverse the initial list, that is done only once.
We traverse those pair of lists and stop half way, accumulating the current item from both lists.
The starting accumulator is either empty or contain the "middle" item depending if the initial list's length is odd/even.

For that we need a function to reverse a list :

```
let reverse xs =
  let rec aux acc = function
    | []      -> acc
    | x :: xs -> aux (x :: acc) xs
  aux [] xs
```

Then we need a function to get the length of a list :

```
// not tail-rec
let rec length = function
  | []      -> 0
  | _ :: xs -> 1 + length xs
```

Finally we can write the required function :

```
let reshuffle xs =
  let reversed = reverse xs

  let rec aux acc = function
    | -1    -> acc
    | index -> let newAcc = xs.[index] :: reversed.[index] :: acc
               aux newAcc (index - 1)

  let theLength = length xs
  let startAcc = if theLength % 2 = 0
                 then []
                 else [ xs.[theLength / 2] ]

  aux startAcc (theLength / 2 - 1)
```

Alternatively, if you think recursing on some index feel as some kind of "cheating" and the recursion should occur on list you could use this instead :
*(Which is shorter but will do "double" job, one half for "nothing")*

```
let reshuffle xs =
  let rec aux acc = function
    | x :: xs, r :: rs -> aux (r :: x :: acc) (xs, rs)
    | _                -> acc

  let full = aux [] (xs, reverse xs)
  full.[.. length xs - 1]
```

We build the full list of "pairs" so we get a list with double size from the initial and symmetric.
And from that we only return the "length" first.

Comment: Can't you reverse and get the length in one iteration?

Comment: @Ringil sure we can, accumulating a counter when we build the reversed and returning a tuple, but that's less reusable IMO

Comment: Well you did talk about being efficient haha :)

Answer (score 2):

`List.last` probably doesn't remove the last element of the list. You can do something like this instead to peel of the last element as well:

```
let rec reshuffle list: List<int> =
  match list with
  | [] -> []
  | head :: tail -> let reverseList = tail |> List.rev
                    match reverseList with
                    | [] -> [head]
                    | lastElement::rest -> [head; lastElement] @ reshuffle (List.rev rest)
```

Note that this is fairly inefficient code with multiple `List.rev`'s, but it should at least do what you want. That said lists don't seem like they would be a very good data structure for this task and using an array internally seems like it would be much better.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks :) I'll let the question open for some time more to see if someone could have a more efficient solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with a small modification of your code:

```
open System

let rec shuffle lst = 
  match lst |> List.length with
  | 0 | 1 -> lst
  | _ -> [lst |> List.head; lst |> List.last] @ shuffle lst.[1..lst.Length - 2]


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

  let data = [1..20]

  shuffle data |> List.iter (printf "%d, ")

  Console.ReadLine() |> ignore

  0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient but IMHO simple.

```
match [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10] with
| [] -> []
| l -> l |> List.rev |> List.tail |> List.rev
```

Answer (score 1):

This first line will return the last item as a list of one item
Then you can pick the last item with `List.head` which return first item of a list of one item in second line

```
let lastItemList = List.toSeq xs |> Seq.skip (xs.Length - 1) |> Seq.toList 
let lastItem = List.head lastItemList
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help.

```
let rec shuffle l =
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | head::rest -> head::(shuffle (List.rev rest));;

shuffle [1.0..5.0];;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible doing this traversing the list only twice:

- Reverse the list and determine its length in one pass
- Construct the result in continuation passing style to avoid reversing the result in an extra pass (which may be considered cheating)

```
let reshuffle xs =
    let rec revLen i acc = function
    | [] -> acc, i
    | x::xs -> revLen (i + 1) (x::acc) xs

    let rec shuffle k = function
    | 0, 0, _, _ -> k []
    | 0, 1, x::xs, _ -> k [x]
    | n, m, x::xs, y::ys -> shuffle (k << fun zs -> x::y::zs) (n - 1, m, xs, ys)
    | _ -> failwith "impossible" 

    let (rs, n) = revLen 0 [] xs
    shuffle id (n / 2, n % 2, xs, rs)
```

Example:

```
reshuffle [1..5]
// val it : int list = [1; 5; 2; 4; 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is the first post you find when searching for "*How to remove the last element of a list in F#*" and I didn't really find *the* one answer, I played around with it (as a beginner) and came to the following solutions where slicing is my favourite (using F# 5.0):

```fs
open System

let chopOffLastElementList (list: List<_>) =
    list.[..(list.Length - 2)]

let chopOffLastElementList2 list =
    match list with
        | [] -> []
        | _ -> list |> List.removeAt (list.Length - 1)

let chopOffLastElementSequence sequence =
    match sequence with
        | sequence when Seq.isEmpty sequence -> Seq.empty
        | _ -> sequence |> Seq.removeAt (Seq.length sequence - 1)


let theList = [8..11]
printfn "List: %A" theList
printfn "List without last element: %A" (chopOffLastElementList theList)

let theList2 = [8..11]
printfn "List 2: %A" theList2
printfn "List 2 without last element: %A" (chopOffLastElementList2 theList2)

let theSequence = seq {8..11}
printfn "Sequence: %A" theSequence
printfn "Sequence without last element: %A" (chopOffLastElementSequence theSequence)
```

Result is

```
List: [8; 9; 10; 11]
List without last element: [8; 9; 10]
List 2: [8; 9; 10; 11]
List 2 without last element: [8; 9; 10]
Sequence: seq [8; 9; 10; 11]
Sequence without last element: seq [8; 9; 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up this simple recursive solution.

```
let rec removeLastElement list = 
 if List.length list = 1 then
   [];
 else
   let head = List.head list;
   let temp = removeLastElement (List.tail list);
   head::temp;
```