# F#: Returning a list with element at index changed

Tags: f#

In F# I need to get a list from an existing list with the value at a particular index changed from the original. All I can find on google and here relates to changing something based on value rather than index (fair enough, because lists don't really have a concept of "index", but I bet everyone knew what I meant).

This is obviously easy enough to code. At the moment I have:

```
// Replace element at index with newElement in seq. Does nothing if index is outside seq.
let updateElement index newElement seq =
    let rec updateElementHelper seq count result =
        match seq with
        | [] -> result |> List.rev
        | head::tail ->
            if count = index then 
                updateElementHelper [] (count + 1) (newElement::result)@tail
            else
                updateElementHelper tail (count + 1) (head::result)
    updateElementHelper seq 0 []
```

which seems to work just fine, but is there a more native way than this?

(F# newbie - or rather, returing after a very long break and never having got all that far the first time around).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to implement this is probably to use the `List.mapi` function - it calls a function you provide for each element of the list and gives you an index, so you can either return the original element or your new element, depending on the index:

```
let updateElement index element list = 
  list |> List.mapi (fun i v -> if i = index then element else v)

updateElement 4 40 [ 0 .. 9 ]
```

As noted by @Jarak, if you need to do this often, then it might be worth thinking whether there is some other more functional approach to your problem where you do not rely on indices - doing something like this would not be very typical thing to do in functional code.

Comment: Thanks. The operation is right at the boundary between the UI and the model. The user will be changing an item in a short array of items on the screen (probably written in C#) so the representation in the model will need to change. I'm trying to keep the model as functional as possible - once I let imperative-style programming across the boundary I'm worried I'll let it infect everything.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you don't want to allow the list to be mutable.  If you did, then you could just index into the list and update the value, e.g. `mylist.[index] <- newValue`.

I will say right now that any operation on a list that uses any other sort of access than the typical "head + tail -> recurse on tail" style is a strong sign that a list isn't the right data structure for your operation.  See e.g. [Juliet's answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984510/6792709)  Typically, if you want to be operating on a linear data structure by index, an array is your best bet.

The easiest way I can think of to do this if you still want to do it with a list, would be something like the following:

```
let newList = oldList.[..index - 1] @ (newValue :: oldList.[index + 1..])
```

(I might possibly have the indices slightly off)

This will probably have very poor performance, however.  I think it would be reasonably fair to say that many F#-ers would call any use of `@` or List slicing a code smell.  As a very infrequent operation on small lists it might be alright, but if it will be used frequently, or on large lists, then it would be a good time to start thinking if a list is really the right collection data structure for your task.

Comment: The use of @ is just to short-circuit the calculation when the right element is found. I originally had

    updateElementHelper [tail] (count + 1) (newElement::result)

Can I make an F# array immutable? There's unlikely to be a significant performance impact, because the length of the list will be in single digits and the operation will be in response to user input (so the short-circuit wasn't necessary, it just seemed pointless *not* to do it).

Comment: ("Pointless not to do it", except that now I'm having trouble reasoning about why the reversals leave everything in the right order, and, behind the scenes, my original is probably doing *exactly* the same as the short-circuited one anyway. Yes, I'll go back to the original having learned a lesson about why @ is frowned on. And it was updateElementHelper tail (count + 1) (newElement::result)), of course, no brackets around tail.

Comment: Ah, a single-digit-length list working in response to user input probably shouldn't be a performance issue, no :)  I was more thinking thousands+ entries lists with high frequency updates.

AFAIK, you can't make an array fully immutable, no - the individual, er, 'cells', can still be updated.  If you need to preserve the original array, there is `Array.copy`, but actually a [persistent list implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) would probably be better for that purpose.

Comment: In fact, your comments and Tomas's prompted me to rethink the implementation, and I'm now doing it as a map from integers to values. The values were true, false, or undefined, so I was using Option<bool>. By switching to a Map I can make the values simply bool and use tryFind to access the values (if I haven't defined a mapping I'll get the None I wanted automatically), so my representation is simplified and I don't have to worry about making sure the list is the right length. All good learning for me!